# Is there a way to use <![if !(IE 8)]> within PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Sorry for the confusing title, I didn't know how I could describe it better.

Anyways, here is the 'problem' I am currently using for my website Cufon. Which works great. However with Internet Explorer 8 it becomes really slow. Therefor I decided to use:

```
<![if !(IE 8)]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myriad-pro.cufonfonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.replace('.example1') ('.example2') ('.example3') ('.example4') ('.example5');
</script>
<![endif]>
```

This works great, however not for everything. Some parts of the scripts, which calls Cufon in the script itself, it doesn't work and Cufon will still be displayed in IE8 (with all negative results from it).

Several included scripts / parts have the following code in it:

```
<?php
echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "$(document).ready(function() { Cufon.replace('.orderpart1') ('.orderpart2') ('.orderpart3'); });";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

Now is it possible to make a same statement as with  within the PHP script(s)? So if it's any browser other than IE8 it will load the Cufon, but if it's IE8 it will not load Cufon?

Hopefully someone understands what I mean here, cause it's kinda hard to explain for me... :(

Comment: You'll want PHP to detect the USER_AGENT, and send the Cufon-related scripts only when the version is not IE8. Try an existing PHP browser-version detection script - rolling your own is guaranteed to not catch that one exception...

Comment: Server-side is not the browser. Just echo all the resources and use [feature detection](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/detection/index.html) to find IE and run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "<![if !(IE 8)]>";
echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "$(document).ready(function() { Cufon.replace('.orderpart1') ('.orderpart2') ('.orderpart3'); });";
echo "</script>";
echo "<![endif]>";
?>
```

is that it ? Or did I misunderstand your request ?

**Edit:**
Another way, as I see that you are using jQuery, could be using [jQuery browser detection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) :

```
<?php
echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "if ( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 8 ) {";
echo "$(document).ready(function() { Cufon.replace('.orderpart1') ('.orderpart2') ('.orderpart3'); });";
echo "}";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

**Please note that this feature is deprecated :**

> This property is available immediately. It is therefore safe to use it to determine whether or not to call $(document).ready(). The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3, and its functionality may be moved to a team-supported plugin in a future release of jQuery.

If you know exactly what kind of feature are needed and aren't implemented in IE8 i would recommend using [`$.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) which is meant for feature detection rather than browser detection.

Comment: Thanks... But will that work? I also thought of that, but I doubt it would work? I could be wrong though...

Comment: Well it shouldn't break your form. PHP is executed server side and Apache or whatever webserver you use serves the HTML result to the client. If it works when you put it directly in the the HTML page it should work when you have PHP echoing it in. I just added the last `;` I had forgotten, dunno if you had putted it back before trying.

Comment: Man... You are correct... Apparently I mixed up your answer with some else's answer. My bad. As you said it is working correctly now. I even tested it with IE8 (in IETester). But since you edited your code, which one should I now use? The first one you gave me, or the 2nd one? Thanks man!

Comment: I would recommend the first one, it uses conditional comments which are widely implemented, whereas the `$.browser` as mentioned in my answer is deprecated.

Comment: One quick (and final) question. Is it also possible to use this rule for not only IE8, but also lower? So for IE8, IE7, IE6 and IE5?

Comment: [see here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for syntax example on what condition you can use. For lower than IE8 or equal to IE8

`<!--[if lte IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower or equal to 8<br />
<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the [HTTP_USER_AGENT](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
$using_ie8 = (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 8.') !== FALSE);
```

but we aware that this can be changed by the user.

[Here is a list of all User Agents for IE](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can use [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) to detect the browser and its version.

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
```

This should return you an array containing browser information.

Note that this will require browscap setting.

Comment: +1 for [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). I was unaware of it.

Comment: The only problem with get_browser() is that you have to maintain an ini file up to date your self if you want to use it extensively [(see this note)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#refsect1-function.get-browser-notes)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can do this by filtering guest's USER AGENT<sup>[***[docs]***](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)</sup>. You can get this from the server variable.

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

USER agent contains all the necessary information of the guest who is opening the page. A simplest usage of this technique I know so far is:

```
if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print the conditional comments as well;

```
<?php
echo "<![if !(IE 8)]>";
echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "$(document).ready(function() { Cufon.replace('.orderpart1') ('.orderpart2') ('.orderpart3'); });";
echo "</script>";
echo "<![endif]>";
?>
```